# Dynamic content depending url params

Tags: jquery, url, dynamic, parameters, utm

I have that jquery script:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('utm_term');

 $(document).ready(function() {

            if (dynamicContent == 'buy') {
        $('#buy').show();
    }

    else {
        $('#default-content').show();
    }
});
```

It's working like this: if `utm_term` param in URL equal `'buy'` then block with `id="buy"` will show. If params are empty or URL don't have params then block with `id="default-content"` will show.

And there is a question: I need that parameter in URL (`utm_term`) not equal some word, but just have it.

Because now if URL have `utm_term=smth_buy`, I see `#default-content`, and I would see `#buy`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use a regexpr:

```
if (dynamicContent.match(/buy/)) {
    $('#buy').show();
}

else {
    $('#default-content').show();
}
```

If you want it case insensitive:

```
if (dynamicContent.match(/buy/i)) {
    $('#buy').show();
}

else {
    $('#default-content').show();
}
```

(`i` flag sets the pattern case insensitive, `bUY` will match same as `BUY`)

Comment: I have one more question. Maybe you know. If i have two conditions (two words like buy and order) "if" in my script, and utm_term="buy_order" it's mean that two different blocks will shown. How i can make that only one condition will work for group of conditions?

Comment: use `or` boolean operator? like `if (dynamicContent.match(/buy/) || dynamicContent.match(/order/))`

Comment: Hmm... Actually i'm saying about this  `if (dynamicContent.match(/buy/i)) {
   $('#title1').show();
  }

 if (dynamicContent.match(/order/i)) {
   $('#title2').show();
  }`

Comment: Ok! I misunderstood, sorry... so use `if... else if` structure is the best way, I think

Comment: But problem that in this case there are will be two title) How i can make that only one of that condition will work if there are two words in url param?

Comment: Can you clarify? So if there Will be two word, what should be the best way? A third title? Match only the first word?

Comment: Yes. the best way only the first word, but only for one group of conditions. And the same rule for other group of conditions. For example: one group of words buy,offer,order; other group doors,windows,floor. Each word have own condition with own block.

Comment: So `if ... else if` won't display to titles :) and to match a group of word, just use something like that : `/(word1|word2)/i` (if there is word1 *or* word2, it will match)

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand. If i use that `/(word1|word2)/i` i can't set different condition for each word. But i need it. You mean `if (dynamicContent.match(/(buy|order)/i)) { $('#title1').show(); }`?

Comment: so if you want different conditions, `if ... else if ... else if ...` There will be only one matching, and put most importants conditions at the beginning

Comment: Thanks, i've read about else if and now i understand. I tested it, everything work. I'm really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Hey Vincent. I note one trouble. When i have clean url without paramets, default-content don't show, because "Cannot read property 'match' of null". Any idea how to fix this?